# Fancybox window is not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using following code to hide url displaying in left bottom of browser on mouseover (NOT to hide link in address bar).
With This class After cliking, a fancybox opens in same window when used through a href method.(In this method, onmouseover, link is shown in left bottom corner).

But Fancybox not get opened when tried with buttons (with buttons, url on left bottom gets hidden). Link gets opened in same window with link in address bar. I want To open fancybox through this onclick function

Code Is As follows

```
    <button class="fancy fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $data['recording_link'];?>'">Play Recording</button>
```

Your help is awaited

Comment: if your using fancy box, just give the button an href of the id of the element you want to display in the fancy box, dont give it an onclick event.

Comment: thnx for comment.Can u explain in detail? i am new in web designing. can you show me sample code with my code data for this ? as in href, php code is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the special `data-fancybox-*` attributes to bind any tag element (including `buttons`) to fancybox, so try this :

```
<button data-fancybox-href="<?php echo $data['recording_link'];?>" class="fancy fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" >Play Recording</button>
```

**Notice** that we don't need the `onclick` attribute

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jEcAB/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank You Very Much. U solved My Problem...Only one thing i should mention that please add javascript $(".fancy").fancybox(); in head section to run this code properly. (Just mentioning this here, so other members can use this properly...

Comment: @drManishJoshi : well, it was assumed that if you got fancybox working,  somehow you included that part of the script. It was also set in the provided jsfiddle though. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to open a fancybox manually. You could laverage fancybox API method [open](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) to open a fancybox.

For example, if you want to open a iframe by clicking a button, you could try this.

HTML

```
<script>
  var url=<?php if(isset($data['recording_link']) && !empty($data['recording_link'])) echo $data['recording_link'];?>;
</script>   
<button onclick="openIframe(url)">test</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  function openIframe(url){
    if(url){
      $.fancybox.open({type:"iframe",href:url});
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: thank you for your help. but unfortunately above code is not working. on clicking on test button, nothing happens...

Comment: any error in console? Please make sure that the openIframe function must be defined before you invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code

```
    <button data-fancybox-href="<?php echo $data['recording_link'];?>" class="fancy fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" >Play Recording</button>
```

And Added javascript code before closing head of page as follows..

```
    <javascript>$(".fancy").fancybox();</script>
```

Thank You JFK (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) For Great Help

I wrote this answer, so in future other members can use this code

Comment: Just beware that `<javascript>` is not a valid tag (that you can close with `</script>`)... better use `<script>` as opening tag. Also beware that if you are including your script in the `<head>` section of your document, it would better to wrap it inside the `.read()` method like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){$(".fancy").fancybox();});`